# Rewriting Permalinks Using Nginx for Wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a wordpress site using Nginx. I am using permalinks and my post pages for category appears like this: http://mysite.com/stores/amazon/. How can I use Nginx rewrite rules to change the link to something like this: http://mysite.com/amazon/ to achieve a shorter url? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a permalink setting than an nginx config. In your example above is stores your category and amazon is your page? If so, your page can be linked to as mysite.com/amazon if your permalink structure is modified to just /%postname%/